# My buttons play all the same sound?

Tags: ios, ios6

Here is my MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController 

@synthesize audioPlayer;
@synthesize soundsArray;

-(void)prepareSounds
{
    NSString *filepath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sounds" ofType:@"plist"];

    self.soundsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

}

- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSString *soundName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(buttonPressed.tag -1)];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    AVAudioPlayer *p = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

    self.audioPlayer = p;

    [self.audioPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction)playSound2:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSString *soundName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(buttonPressed.tag -2)];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    AVAudioPlayer *p = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

    self.audioPlayer = p;

    [self.audioPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction)playSound3:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSString *soundName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(buttonPressed.tag -3)];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    AVAudioPlayer *p = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

    self.audioPlayer = p;

    [self.audioPlayer play];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{    
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

My MainViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSArray *soundsArray;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *soundsArray;

-(void)prepareSounds;
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)playSound2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)playSound3:(id)sender;

@end
```

In the 'Supporting Files' folder I have an array of strings with the name of the sound files I want to play, and in the 'Supporting Files' folder I have a folder named 'Sounds', which contains the sound files.

All of my buttons play the same sound.  Can someone please provide some insight.  Thanks!

Comment: Try logging when each of your playSound's are called and also log the string of the filename that they are going to play. This will tell you if the right methods are being called, and if you are getting the right sound file string.

Comment: Why you added 3 methods for doing the same task ? Why don't you reuse the code ? In your above code why don't you hardcode the sound name ?

Comment: @user2420837: I'll post my answer, before that tell me how did you add tags for each button and what is the name of those sound names ?

Comment: The tags for the buttons are 1, 2, 3 etc, and the sound names are sound1, sound2, sound3

Comment: NSLog the file path in all three methods. As It looks like only the first object in the array is getting called only. Put objectAtIndex:(sender.tag-1) only.

Comment: @Zen: (sender.tag-1) returns an error "property 'tag' not found on object of type strong id"

Comment: @user2420837 To get rid of that, typecast the sender with `UIButton` as `UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;` then use btn.tag instead of sender.tag.

Comment: @Zen: The one sound plays even when I delete the .plist file. Am I referencing the sound in the wrong place or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: prepareSounds() was never called.  Here is the working code:

```
    #import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController 

@synthesize audioPlayer;
@synthesize soundsArray;

-(void)prepareSounds
{    
    NSString *filepath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"plist"];

    self.soundsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

}

- (void)stopAudio
{
    if (audioPlayer!= nil) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
        //do some task for changing the Image i.e setting the default image
    }

}

- (IBAction)playSound:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

    NSString *soundName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(btn.tag - 1)];

    NSString *path      = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *file         = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    AVAudioPlayer *p    = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

    self.audioPlayer    = p;

    if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
    {
        [self stopAudio];
    }

    [self.audioPlayer play];


}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self prepareSounds];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{    
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be in this line playSound:

```
NSString *soundName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(buttonPressed.tag -1)]
```

which is repeated in playSound2 and playSound3 with "buttonPressed.tag -2" and "buttonPressed.tag -3".

If your buttonPressed.tags are set to 1, 2, and 3, then each time "buttonPressed.tag -X" is likely evaluating to 0, and playing the sound of the first file in the array.

Comment: Then how would I reference the sound to play?

Comment: If your buttonPressed.tag for each button is set to 1, 2, 3 and you have three files in the array at index 0, 1, 2, change playSound2: and playSound3 to also have "buttonPressed.tag -1" instead of "buttonPressed.tag -2" and "buttonPressed.tag -3".

Comment: @JakeSpencer: Yes, you are correct. +1 for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

You are repeating the code to do the same task.

Add all your buttons `IBAction` to a single method (say it as `playSound`)

Implement the method like:

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(UIButton *)sender
{

    NSString *soundName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(sender.tag -1)];

    NSString *path      = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *file         = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    AVAudioPlayer *p    = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

    self.audioPlayer    = p;

    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

There is no need of writing same code for each individual button.

Comment: Then how do I get it to play a different sound for each button?

Comment: When you press on 1st button it's tag is 1. then this `[soundsArray objectAtIndex:(sender.tag -1)];` evaluates as `[soundsArray objectAtIndex:0];` AND When you press on 2nd button it's tag is 2. then this `[soundsArray objectAtIndex:(sender.tag -1)];` evaluates as `[soundsArray objectAtIndex:1];` AND When you press on 3rd button it's tag is 3. then this `[soundsArray objectAtIndex:(sender.tag -1)];` evaluates as `[soundsArray objectAtIndex:2];`

Comment: I understand that, so I just put the tag to the buttons like 1,2,3, and changed all of the [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(sender.tag -1)];  It seems like it should work, but it doesn't :/

Comment: If it means anything, when I delete the sound that keeps playing, and clean the build and delete the app from the simulator, re-run it, it then plays another different sound that is in the folder.

Comment: @user2420837: check the file names in the array

Comment: The one sound plays even when I delete the .plist file.  Am I referencing the sound in the wrong place or something?